# How does a servlet's URL pattern correspond to Spring MVC's mappings?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In the web.xml file you have such entry

```
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

What do I need this *.jsp for? Because if I declare a **method** in a controller say with request mapping `/helloworld/method1` I can access that method even using such path(e.g. `/helloworld/method1`) - without the .jsp in the end isn't it?

So what does that *.jsp do there?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Do you mind explaining the answer, instead of just link? I didn't get what was on that link and how it relates with my question

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Hopefully you or someone else will do so as I could totally not understand how that link answers my question

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard So can you extend?

Comment: is there no answer??

Answer (score 0):

In general we uses the web.xml for the servlet mapping. Similar to the following what you have given in the question.

```
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

**what is servlet-name** - This means you have a servlet with HelloWeb logical name. 
**What is URL-pattern**  - URL pattern tell when to invoke the servlet. *.jsp means any URL which is ending with .jsp will invoke the HelloWeb Servlet like following
 **localhost:52575/order/index.jsp**  
**localhost:52575/order/history.jsp** 
Above URLs will invoke the HelloWeb Servlet. 
But URL which is not ending with .jsp will invoke some other servlet which you will define separately.